# Zend Framework - which decorators to use?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I want to change the html markup. I want to change the `<dl>` for a `<div>` tag and wrap the **label and element** together in a `<div>` tag so that I can apply floats to them. 
 At the moment my element output looks like this:

```
<fieldset id="fieldset-languages">
    <legend>Languages</legend>
    <dl>

        <dt id="lang1-label">
            <label for="lang1" class="optional">Language</label>
        </dt>
        <dd id="lang1-element">
            <select name="lang1" id="lang1" class="input-select">
                <option value="0" label="English">English</option>
                <option value="1" label="French">French</option>
            </select>
        </dd>

        <dt id="lang2-label">
            <label for="lang1" class="optional">Language</label>
        </dt>
        <dd id="lang2-element">
            <select name="lang2" id="lang2" class="input-select">
                <option value="0" label="German">German</option>
                <option value="1" label="Spanish">Spanish</option>
            </select>
        </dd>

    </dl>
</fieldset>
```

and I want to change it to this...

```
<fieldset id="fieldset-languages">
    <legend>Languages</legend>
    <div>
        <div>
            <p id="lang1-label">
                <label for="lang1" class="optional">Language</label>
            </p>
            <p id="lang1-element">
                <select name="lang1" id="lang1" class="input-select">
                    <option value="0" label="English">English</option>
                    <option value="1" label="French">French</option>
                </select>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p id="lang2-label">
                <label for="lang1" class="optional">Language</label>
            </p>
            <p id="lang2-element">
                <select name="lang2" id="lang2" class="input-select">
                    <option value="0" label="German">German</option>
                    <option value="1" label="Spanish">Spanish</option>
                </select>
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I've already figured out I can change the dt/dd to `<p>` tags using the Html decorator - but can't wrap the label and element in a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your decorators should look like this (just an example):

```
      $this->setDecorators(array(
         'ViewHelper',
          array('Description', array('tag' => 'p', 'class' => 'description')),
          'Errors',
          array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div')),
          array('Label', array('tag' => 'p')),
          array(array('elementDiv' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div')),
      ));
```

you can read the "**Customizing Output Using Standard Decorators**" section of [this article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450)
at least, it was helpful for me to understand how the form decorators works

quoted from the article:

> "When adding a decorator, you have the option to alias it. What
>   this does is allow you to store the decorator using a different name
>   -- which allows you to retrieve it from the stack by that name. This
>   is primarily useful when you need to add two or more of the same type
>   of decorator; in fact, in such a situation, if you do not alias, the
>   last registered decorator of that type will overwrite all other
>   instances! You accomplish aliasing by passing an array as the
>   decorator type, with a single key/value pair with the alias as the
>   key, and the decorator type as the value. For instance, if you needed
>   to use two different HTML tags in your stack, you could do something
>   like the following ..."

(keep on reading this part of the section  ;-))